# Using amp-analytics - no vendor : get http error 405 when try to send data to my page

Tags: analytics, amp-html, http-status-code-405

Working on using amp-analytics - no vendor implementation: get an error code 405 from transport.js, line 84 (AMP library) when sending the parameters to the page collecting the data.

transport.js: lien with the issue is:

```
const result = win.navigator.sendBeacon(request, '');
```

Full code:

```
...
/**
       * @param {!Window} win
       * @param {string} request
       * @return {boolean} True if this browser supports navigator.sendBeacon.
       */
      static sendRequestUsingBeacon(win, request) {
        if (!win.navigator.sendBeacon) {
          return false;
        }
        const result = win.navigator.sendBeacon(request, '');
        if (result) {
          dev().fine(TAG_, 'Sent beacon request', request);
        }
        return result;
      }
...
```

I get no other error code in the page, and using `#development=1` in the URL I get the `AMP validation successful` message in the browser's console.

My code sending the pageview:

```
<amp-analytics>
      <script type="application/json">
      {
        "requests": {
          "pageview": "https://tru.am/scripts/custom/wigwamvlad.js?clientID=${clientId}&version=${version}&canonical=${canonical}&ogURL=${ogURL}&referrer=${referrer}&title=${title}&image=${image}&callback=${callback}"
        },
        "triggers": {
          "trackPageview": {
            "on": "visible",
            "request": "pageview",
            "vars": {
              "eventId": "pageview",
              "clientId": "1182",
              "version" : "13",
              "canonical": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tru-am-dev/promote/test.amp.tru.am.analytics.html",
              "ogURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/tru-am-dev/promote/test.amp.tru.am.analytics.html",
              "referrer": "TBA",
              "title": "test page for AMP analytics",
              "image": "http://www.trueanthem.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/about_bottom.jpg",
              "callback": "eqwest_1502748414821"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      </script>
      </amp-analytics>
```

Any help/guidance/tip will be appreciated.

[ADDITION] The 405 message I get is:

```
Request URL:https://tru.am/scripts/ta-pagesocial-sdk.js?1182&version=12&canonical=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Ftru-am-dev%2Fpromote%2Ftest.amp.6.analytics.html&ogURL=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Ftru-am-dev%2Fpromote%2Ftest.amp.6.analytics.html&referrer=TBA&title=test%20page%20for%20AMP%20analytics&image=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.trueanthem.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F03%2Fabout_bottom.jpg&callback=eqwest_1502748414821
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 
Remote Address:104.25.163.34:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: Can you include the 405 error message?

Comment: Is thi what you need?:Request URL:https://tru.am/scripts/ta-pagesocial-sdk.js?1182&version=12&canonical=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Ftru-am-dev%2Fpromote%2Ftest.amp.6.analytics.html&ogURL=https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Ftru-am-dev%2Fpromote%2Ftest.amp.6.analytics.html&referrer=TBA&title=test%20page%20for%20AMP%20analytics&image=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.trueanthem.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F03%2Fabout_bottom.jpg&callback=eqwest_1502748414821
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 
Remote Address:104.25.163.34:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Updated in the description of the issue (bottom)